# Java 8 Optional asSet()

Tags: java, guava, java-8, option-type

So I have been using Guava's `Optional` for a while now, and I'm moving to Java 8 so I wanted to use its `Optional` class, but it doesn't have my favorite method from Guava: `asSet()`. Is there a way to do this with the Java 8 `Optional` that I am not seeing. I love being able to treat `Optional` as a collection so I can do this:

```
for (final User u : getUserOptional().asSet()) {
   return u.isPermitted(getPermissionRequired());
}
```

In some cases avoids the need for an additional variable.

For example:

```
 Optional<User> optUser = getUserOptional();
 if (optUser.isPresent()) {
     return optUser.get().isPermitted(getPermissionRequired());
 }
```

Is there an easy way to replicate the Guava style in Java 8's `Optional`?

Thanks

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725537/using-java-8s-optional-with-streamflatmap

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a simple way of converting an `Optional` into a `Set`. It works just like any other conversion of an `Optional`:

Given an `Optional<T> o` you can invoke

```
o.map(Collections::singleton).orElse(Collections.emptySet())
```

to get a `Set<T>`. If you don’t like the idea of `Collections.emptySet()` being called in every case you can turn it into a lazy evaluation:

```
o.map(Collections::singleton).orElseGet(Collections::emptySet)
```

however, the method is too trivial to make a performance difference. So it’s just a matter of coding style.

You can also use it to iterate like intended:

```
for(T t: o.map(Collections::singleton).orElse(Collections.emptySet()))
    // do something with t, may include a return statement
```

Comment: @csyperski I don't see why you would want to stick with this empty Set + for loop trick you used with Guava, when you can simply perform the required operation (the one that is currently inside the loop) on the optional, and have a default value if the optional is empty - `return optUser.map(u -> u.isPermitted(getPermissionRequired())).orElse(Boolean.FALSE)`.

Comment: Because is this case it works, but it doesn't always.  Lets say we have the following:  public Optional<User> attemptLogin(String email, .... ) {
        // first lets see if the user is banned
        for ( final FailedLogin failedLogin : getFailedLogin(email, ipAddress).map(Collections::singleton).orElseGet(Collections::emptySet) ) {
            logger.warn("Account is currently banned {}", failedLogin);
            return Optional.empty();
        }
 // perform other login validations
}.  This may not be the best example, but it is one I just saw in some legacy code.

Comment: @Eran: your solution works if returning a certain fixed value is an alternative. However, if not returning but proceeding with the next statement is desired, it won’t. Still, thinking about a redesign which has not this requirement is recommended.

Answer (score 5):

You appear to only be using `asSet` so you can write a for loop, but that's unnecessary in Java 8.  Instead of your code

```
Optional<User> optUser = getUserOptional();
if ( optUser.isPresent() ) {
    return optUser.get().isPermitted(getPermissionRequired());
}
```

you could write

```
getUserPresent().map(optUser -> optUser.isPermitted(getPermissionRequired()))
   .orElse(false);
```

...or, in many cases, you could use `Optional.ifPresent(Consumer<T>)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` :

```
return optUser.map(u -> u.isPermitted(getPermissionRequired()));
```

But it would return an `Optional<WhateverTypeIsPermittedReturns>`.

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-)

> public  Optional map(Function mapper)
>
> If a value is present, apply the provided mapping function to it, and
>   if the result is non-null, return an Optional describing the result.
>   Otherwise return an empty Optional.

Comment: So in this instance I guess I could just do: return optUser.map(u -> u.isPermitted(getPermissionRequired())).get(); and it would have the came effect.

Comment: @csyperski get() throws an exception if the optional has no value, so I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: @csyperski If you want null in case no value is present, use `.orElse(null)`.

Comment: but it this case it would return a boolean so calling get would be safe to unwrap the boolean, right?

Comment: @csyperski I think if `isPermitted` returns boolean, map operation would return Optional<Boolean>, so calling get on it would throw an exception if it's empty (i.e. if the original Optional<User> is empty). That's why you should use .orElse, and supply a default value (example : `.orElse(Boolean.FALSE)`).

Answer (score 1):

I also don't see a really elegant, built-in way to do this, but would like to propose a solution similar to that of Dici:

```
public static <T> Set<T> asSet(Optional<T> opt) {
    return opt.isPresent() ?
        Collections.singletonSet(opt.get()) :
        Collections.emptySet();
}
```

This avoids the creation of a new `HashSet` instance and the insertion of the optional object. (Note: This is basically the "inlined" version of what Guavas `Present` and `Absent` classes do: The `Present` class returns the `singletonSet`, and the `Absent` class returns the `emptySet`).

The usage would be similar to your original pattern:

```
for( final User u : asSet(getUserOptional()) ) {
   return u.isPermitted(getPermissionRequired());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your getUserOptional so that it returns a Set or implement your own asSet method :

```
public Set<User> getUserOptional() {
     Optional<User> optUser;
     //your code
     Set<User> result = new HashSet<>();
     if (optUser.isPresent())
         result.add(optUser.get());
     return result;
}
```

or

```
public static <T> Set<T> asSet(Optional<T> opt) {
    Set<T> result = new HashSet<>();
    if (opt.isPresent())
        result.add(opt.get());
    return result;
}
```

I don't know if there is a built-in way to do it however.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, it's just not as elegant in my mind.  To me it makes sense to think of Optionals as a collection of zero or one item and then process them as such.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is:

```
getUserOptional().stream().collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

I'm not convinced this is better, but just wanted to add it here for completeness.