# Why is there no Optional.mapToInt() in Java8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

In Java8 streams I can use the `mapToInt` method to create an `IntStream`, which will return `OptionalInt`s for some actions (like `findFirst`). Why isn't there anything similar in `Optional`?

```
int i = Stream
        .of("1") // just as an example
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt) // mapToInt exists for streams
        .findFirst() // this even returns an OptionalInt!
        .getAsInt(); // quite handy

int j = Optional
        .of("1") // same example
        .map(Integer::parseInt) // no mapToInt available
        .get().intValue(); // not as handy as for streams
```

Comment: This is a quote from Brian Goetz: "The set of "obvious" methods requested to be added to Optional is seemingly infinite". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28796324/optional-vs-throwing-an-exception

Comment: Because `OptionalInt` and other special-case methods exists only to avoid many boxing/unboxing operations.

Comment: Why is `.getAsInt()` so much better than `.get().intValue()`? And what about simply calling `get()`, omitting the obsolete `intValue()` call?

Answer (score 9):

Apparently a handful of additional methods will appear in Optionals in Java-9. However it's unlikely that `mapToInt` will be added. I [discussed](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2015-September/035424.html) this problem several days before in core-libs-dev. Here's Paul Sandoz [answer](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2015-September/035426.html):

> I don’t wanna go there, my response is transform `Optional*` into a `*Stream`. An argument for adding `mapOrElseGet` (notice that the primitive variants return `U`) is that other functionality can be composed from it.

And [later](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2015-September/035457.html):

> I think it’s fine to to pollute OptionalInt etc with Optional but i want to avoid it for the other direction.

In general I think it's reasonable. The purpose of primitive streams is to improve the performance when you process many primitive values. However for `Optional` the performance gain of using the primitive value is quite marginal if any (there are much bigger chances compared to streams that extra boxing will by optimized out by JIT-compiler). Also even though project [Valhalla](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/valhalla/) will not appear in Java-9, it's gradually moving forward and it's possible that in Java-10 we will finally see generics-over-primitives, so these primitive optionals will become completely unnecessary. In this context adding more interoperability between Object `Optional` and primitive `OptionalInt` seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 8):

It makes sense to have specializations in the `Stream` API as a stream may represent bulk operations processing millions of elements, thus the performance impact can be dramatic. But as far as I know, even this decision wasn’t without a controversy.

For an `Optional`, carrying at most *one* element, the performance impact is not justifying additional APIs (if there ever is an impact). It’s not quite clear whether `OptionalInt`, etc. are really necessary at all.

Regarding the convenience, I can’t get your point. The following works:

```
int j = Optional.of("1").map(Integer::parseInt).get();
```

your proposal is to add another API which allows to rewrite the above statement as

```
int j = Optional.of("1").mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).getAsInt();
```

I don’t see how this raises the convenience…

But following the logic, with Java 9, you can write

```
int j = Optional.of("1").stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).findFirst().getAsInt();
```

which raises this kind of “convenience” even more…

Answer (score -1):

The following also works quite nicely:

```java
int j = Optional
        .of("1")
        .map(Integer::parseInt)
        .map(OptionalInt::of)         // -> Optional<OptionalInt>
        .orElse(OptionalInt.empty())  // -> OptionalInt
        .getAsInt();
```

The trick is to map `Optional<Integer>` to `Optional<OptionalInt>` and then unwrap the inner `OptionalInt`. Thus, as far as the `Optional` is concerned, no primitive `int` is involved, so it works with Java generics.

One advantage of this approach is that it doesnt need autoboxing. That's an important point for me as we enabled warnings for autoboxing in our project, primarily to prevent unnecessary boxing and unboxing operations.

I stumbled upon this problem and the solution while implementing a public method that returns an `OptionalInt`, where the implementation uses another method returning `Optional<Something>`.
I didn't want to return `Optional<Integer>` from my public method, so I searched for something like `Optional.mapToInt` just like you.

But after reading the responses of **Holger** and **Tagir Valeev**, I agree that it's perfectly reasonable to omit such a method in the JDK. There are enough alternatives available.