# How to create a List<T> from Map<K,V> and List<K> of keys?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Using Java 8 lambdas, what's the "best" way to effectively create a new `List<T>` given a `List<K>` of possible keys and a `Map<K,V>`?  This is the scenario where you are given a `List` of possible `Map` keys and are expected to generate a `List<T>` where `T` is some type that is constructed based on some aspect of `V`, the map value types.

I've explored a few and don't feel comfortable claiming one way is better than another (with maybe one exception -- see code).  I'll clarify "best" as a combination of code clarity and runtime efficiency.  These are what I came up with.  I'm sure someone can do better, which is one aspect of this question.  I don't like the `filter` aspect of most as it means needing to create intermediate structures and multiple passes over the names `List`.  Right now, I'm opting for Example 6 -- a plain 'ol loop.  (*NOTE: Some cryptic thoughts are in the code comments, especially "need to reference externally..." This means external from the lambda.*)

```
public class Java8Mapping {
    private final Map<String,Wongo> nameToWongoMap = new HashMap<>();
    public Java8Mapping(){
        List<String> names = Arrays.asList("abbey","normal","hans","delbrook");
        List<String> types = Arrays.asList("crazy","boring","shocking","dead");
        for(int i=0; i<names.size(); i++){
            nameToWongoMap.put(names.get(i),new Wongo(names.get(i),types.get(i)));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("in main");
        Java8Mapping j = new Java8Mapping();
        List<String> testNames = Arrays.asList("abbey", "froderick","igor");
        System.out.println(j.getBongosExample1(testNames).stream().map(Bongo::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
        System.out.println(j.getBongosExample2(testNames).stream().map(Bongo::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
        System.out.println(j.getBongosExample3(testNames).stream().map(Bongo::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
        System.out.println(j.getBongosExample4(testNames).stream().map(Bongo::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
        System.out.println(j.getBongosExample5(testNames).stream().map(Bongo::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
        System.out.println(j.getBongosExample6(testNames).stream().map(Bongo::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
    }

    private static class Wongo{
        String name;
        String type;
        public Wongo(String s, String t){name=s;type=t;}
        @Override public String toString(){return "Wongo{name="+name+", type="+type+"}";}
    }

    private static class Bongo{
        Wongo wongo;
        public Bongo(Wongo w){wongo = w;}
        @Override public String toString(){ return "Bongo{wongo="+wongo+"}";}
    }

    // 1:  Create a list externally and add items inside 'forEach'.
    //     Needs to externally reference Map and List
    public List<Bongo> getBongosExample1(List<String> names){
        final List<Bongo> listOne = new ArrayList<>();
        names.forEach(s -> {
                  Wongo w = nameToWongoMap.get(s);
                  if(w != null) {
                      listOne.add(new Bongo(nameToWongoMap.get(s)));
                  }
              });
        return listOne;
    }

    // 2: Use stream().map().collect()
    //    Needs to externally reference Map
    public List<Bongo> getBongosExample2(List<String> names){
        return names.stream()
              .filter(s -> nameToWongoMap.get(s) != null)
              .map(s -> new Bongo(nameToWongoMap.get(s)))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    // 3: Create custom Collector
    //    Needs to externally reference Map
    public List<Bongo> getBongosExample3(List<String> names){
        Function<List<Wongo>,List<Bongo>> finisher = list -> list.stream().map(Bongo::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
        Collector<String,List<Wongo>,List<Bongo>> bongoCollector =
              Collector.of(ArrayList::new,getAccumulator(),getCombiner(),finisher, Characteristics.UNORDERED);

        return names.stream().collect(bongoCollector);
    }
    // example 3 helper code
    private BiConsumer<List<Wongo>,String> getAccumulator(){
        return (list,string) -> {
            Wongo w = nameToWongoMap.get(string);
            if(w != null){
                list.add(w);
            }
        };
    }
    // example 3 helper code
    private BinaryOperator<List<Wongo>> getCombiner(){
        return (l1,l2) -> {
            l1.addAll(l2);
            return l1;
        };
    }

    // 4: Use internal Bongo creation facility
    public List<Bongo> getBongosExample4(List<String> names){
        return names.stream().filter(s->nameToWongoMap.get(s) != null).map(s-> new Bongo(nameToWongoMap.get(s))).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    // 5: Stream the Map EntrySet.  This avoids referring to anything outside of the stream, 
    // but bypasses the lookup benefit from Map.
    public List<Bongo> getBongosExample5(List<String> names){
        return nameToWongoMap.entrySet().stream().filter(e->names.contains(e.getKey())).map(e -> new Bongo(e.getValue())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    // 6: Plain-ol-java loop
    public List<Bongo> getBongosExample6(List<String> names){
        List<Bongo> bongos = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String s : names){
            Wongo w = nameToWongoMap.get(s);
            if(w != null){
                bongos.add(new Bongo(w));
            }
        }
        return bongos;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have `K` and `V`, but what's `T`?

Comment: @user2357112 Edited.  T is some type not in the map, but is constructed using the map values.  Hope that helps.

Comment: plain-ol-java for the win!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `namesToWongoMap` is an instance variable, you can't really avoid a capturing lambda.

You can clean up the stream by splitting up the operations a little more:

```java
return names.stream()
    .map(n -> namesToWongoMap.get(n))
    .filter(w -> w != null)
    .map(w -> new Bongo(w))
    .collect(toList());
```

```java
return names.stream()
    .map(namesToWongoMap::get)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(Bongo::new)
    .collect(toList());
```

That way you don't call `get` twice.

This is very much like the `for` loop, except, for example, it could theoretically be parallelized if `namesToWongoMap` can't be mutated concurrently.

> I don't like the `filter` aspect of most as it means needing to create intermediate structures and multiple passes over the names `List`.

There are no intermediate structures and there is only one pass over the `List`. A stream pipeline says "for each element...do this sequence of operations". Each element is visited once and the pipeline is applied.

Here are some relevant quotes from the [`java.util.stream` package description](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#package.description):

> A stream is not a data structure that stores elements; instead, it conveys elements from a source such as a data structure, an array, a generator function, or an I/O channel, through a pipeline of computational operations.
>
> Processing streams lazily allows for significant efficiencies; in a pipeline such as the filter-map-sum example above, filtering, mapping, and summing can be fused into a single pass on the data, with minimal intermediate state.

Comment: Nice.  Simple and clean.  I like it!

Comment: I think I'm going to sit on this for a day or two and see of others chime in.  I'm interested to see if anyone can come up with something better, although I doubt it.  :)

Answer (score 7):

[Radiodef's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30538924/1441122) pretty much nailed it, I think. The solution given there:

```
return names.stream()
    .map(namesToWongoMap::get)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(Bongo::new)
    .collect(toList());
```

is probably about the best that can be done in Java 8.

I did want to mention a small wrinkle in this, though. The `Map.get` call returns `null` if the name isn't present in the map, and this is subsequently filtered out. There's nothing wrong with this *per se*, though it does bake null-means-not-present semantics into the pipeline structure.

In some sense we'd want a mapper pipeline operation that has a choice of returning zero or one elements. A way to do this with streams is with `flatMap`. The flatmapper function can return an arbitrary number of elements into the stream, but in this case we want just zero or one. Here's how to do that:

```
return names.stream()
    .flatMap(name -> {
        Wongo w = nameToWongoMap.get(name);
        return w == null ? Stream.empty() : Stream.of(w);
    })
    .map(Bongo::new)
    .collect(toList());
```

I admit this is pretty clunky and so I wouldn't recommend doing this. A slightly better but somewhat obscure approach is this:

```
return names.stream()
    .flatMap(name -> Optional.ofNullable(nameToWongoMap.get(name))
                             .map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty))
    .map(Bongo::new)
    .collect(toList());
```

but I'm still not sure I'd recommend this as it stands.

The use of `flatMap` does point to another approach, though. If you have a more complicated policy of how to deal with the not-present case, you could refactor this into a helper function that returns a Stream containing the result or an empty Stream if there's no result.

Finally, JDK 9 -- still under development as of this writing -- has added `Stream.ofNullable` which is useful in exactly these situations:

```
return names.stream()
    .flatMap(name -> Stream.ofNullable(nameToWongoMap.get(name)))
    .map(Bongo::new)
    .collect(toList());
```

As an aside, JDK 9 has also added `Optional.stream` which creates a zero-or-one stream from an `Optional`. This is useful in cases where you want to call an Optional-returning function from within `flatMap`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22726869/1441122) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22822592/1441122) for more discussion.

Comment: I already added [StreamEx.ofNullable(obj)](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#ofNullable-T-) and [StreamEx.of(Optional)](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/javax/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#of-java.util.Optional-) to my library. Actually even without 3rd-party libs and moving to JDK9 anyone can create similar static methods in some project-specific utility class and use them.

Answer (score 3):

One approach I didn't see is `retainAll`:

```
public List<Bongo> getBongos(List<String> names) {
    Map<String, Wongo> copy = new HashMap<>(nameToWongoMap);
    copy.keySet().retainAll(names);

    return copy.values().stream().map(Bongo::new).collect(
        Collectors.toList());
}
```

The extra Map is a minimal performance hit, since it's just copying pointers to objects, not the objects themselves.

Comment: Weeelllll...I think there is a *relatively* high amount of overhead associated with creating all of the nodes for each entry. Going off of  [this older article](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/08/java-best-practices-vector-arraylist.html).  But your answer if nice and clean, and the overhead may not be a factor.