# Cast from Optional<> to ArrayList<>

Tags: java, arraylist, casting, option-type

I have the following situation:

```
public ArrayList<A> getMethods(){
    return b.c.test();
}
```

So, my problem is that `b.c.test()` returns a value with `Optional<A>` as return type. But I need to return an `ArrayList<A>`.

So, I tried to cast it and rewrite it to :

```
public ArrayList<A> getMethods(){
    return (ArrayList<A>)b.c.test();
}
```

But Eclipse says that such a cast from `Optional<A>` to `ArrayList<A>` is **not possible.**

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Well yes, an `Optional` is not an `ArrayList`, they certainly cannot be cast.  What do you mean you "can not change it"?  What is "it" and why can't it be changed?

Comment: what is `Optianal<A>` ?

Comment: @ShadowRay https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html

Comment: it is a not a Collection, what do you mean by "cast" to ArrayList ?

Comment: @ShadowRay "what is `Optianal<A>`?" if your question is general then: it is very nice thing added from Guava to Java 8. It hleps us avoid ing nulls https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained

Comment: @dimo414: I mean that I need a ArrayList<A> as return type. Therefore, I can not change it.

Comment: @TNT they could be using Guava's [`Optional`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html), they haven't specified.

Comment: Why `ArrayList`? If your client code is depending on it, your client code is broken; you should be returning a singleton list.

Answer (score 32):

I am presuming your intended semantic is 'if the value is present return a list with a single item, otherwise return an empty list.' In that case I would suggest something like the following:

```
ArrayList<A> result = new ArrayList<>();
b.c.test().ifPresent(result::add);
return result;
```

However I would suggest your return type should be `List<A>` rather than `ArrayList<A>` as that gives you the opportunity to change the type of list without changing the callers. It would also allow you to return `Collections.EMPTY_LIST` if the optional value is not present which is more efficient than creating an unnecessary `ArrayList`.

**Update**: there's now an easier option with Java 9:

```
b.c.test().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Update**: and even easier option with Java 16:

```
b.c.test().stream().toList();
```

Answer (score 26):

In this case, it is possible to not use streams at all:

```
public static <T> List<T> toList(Optional<T> opt) {
    return opt.isPresent()
            ? Collections.singletonList(opt.get())
            : Collections.emptyList();
}
```

Or, the same code using the functional API:

```
public static <T> List<T> toList(Optional<T> opt) {
    return opt
            .map(Collections::singletonList)
            .orElseGet(Collections::emptyList);
}
```

I prefer the upper variant because I know for sure that it doesn't create any unnecessary objects on the Java heap.

Answer (score 7):

If everyone insists on using streams for this issue, it should be more idiomatic than using `ifPresent()`
Unfortunately, Java 8 does not have a `Optional.stream()` method, so it is not possible to do:

```
 optional.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

see also: [Using Java 8's Optional with Stream::flatMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725537/using-java-8s-optional-with-streamflatmap)

But in JDK 9, it will be added (and that code actually already runs on Java 9)

```
Optional<Integer> o = Optional.empty();
final List<Integer> list = o.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
return b.c.test()
    .map(Arrays::asList).map(ArrayList::new)
    .orElseGet(ArrayList::new);
```

If the optional has a value, it "maps" it to a `List<A>` with `Arrays.asList` and then to an `ArrayList` via the `new ArrayList<A>(List<A>)` constructor; otherwise it yields an empty `ArrayList` via the empty constructor.

This could be more explicitly written out as:

```
return b.c.test()
    .map(value -> new ArrayList<A>(Arrays.asList(value)))
    .orElseGet(() -> new ArrayList<A>());
```

Comment: This seems excessively verbose; isn't this actually misusing Java 8's functional idioms for a very simple task?

Comment: I dunno, I like this style. I like the lack of temporary variables. I see the complexity as a consequence of the overly specific return type. If it were `List` instead of `ArrayList` this could be written more straightforwardly: `map(Collections::singletonList).orElseGet(Collections::emptyList)`. I like the way that looks.

Comment: IMO, the temporary variable in @sprinter's answer makes the code more readable (and much more concise). `map` and `orElseGet` are useful -- when used in the right place. Your solution just reminded me of the caveats presented in [Guava's Functionals Explained](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained) -- imperative code should be the default, even in Java 8.

Answer (score 2):

**With Java9,** you can do this using the newly added `Optional::stream API` :

```
Optional<List<A>> list;
List<A> collect = list.stream()
               .flatMap(Optional::stream)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

## Since Java 9

```
return b.c.test().stream()
                 .collect(toList());
```

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

## Since Java 8

```
return b.c.test()
           .map(List::of)
           .orElse(emptyList());
```

import static java.util.Collections.emptyList;

Answer (score 0):

An Optional is a container object which may or may not contain a non-null value.

In ArrayList terms I would translate it as an array which has 0 or 1 members.

```
public ArrayList<A> getMethods(){
  Optional<A> opt = b.c.test();
  ArrayList<A> res = new ArrayList<>();
  if ( opt.isPresent() )
    res.add( opt.get() );
  return res;
}
```

Comment: [`Optional.empty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#empty--) is a static method that returns a new, empty `Optional`.  You want [`Optional.isPresent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#isPresent--).  There are also cleaner ways to do this (@sprinter's answer).

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos I think you mean `if (opt.isPresent())` rather than `if (!opt.isPresent())`. At the moment this will throw an exception when you try to `get` and empty optional.

Comment: Of course, that is what happens for changing blindly !opt.empty() for !opt.isPresent().

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Guava's [`Optional`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html), you can do:

```
return new ArrayList<>(b.c.test().asSet());
```

This will extract the value from the `Optional` (if present) and add it to a new `ArrayList`.

If you're using Java 8, @sprinter's answer is what you need.