# How to convert ArrayList<Optional<Test>> to ArrayList<Test>

Tags: java, collections, option-type

```
 ArrayList<Optional<Test>> valueList= vv.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I'm getting the values into a list with the `ArrayList<Optional<Test>>` as the return type but I need to convert it to `ArrayList<Test>` without an optional return type.

How do I convert `ArrayList<Optional<Test>>`  to  `ArrayList<Test>` in Java 8 or Java 7?

Comment: Not your fault, but I consider that a poor design. They should have preferred to give you a `List<Test>` from the outset. I at least see no point in the `Optional` here.

Comment: What is your desired result? Do you want a shorter list with the non-present items removed, or do you want `null` in their place?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cast from Optional<> to ArrayList<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688382/cast-from-optional-to-arraylist)

Answer (score 3):

**1.Using filter()**

One option in Java 8 is to filter out the values with `Optional::isPresent` and then perform mapping with the `Optional::get` function to extract values:

```
ArrayList<Test> testlist = valueList.stream()
  .filter(Optional::isPresent)
  .map(Optional::get)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**2.Using flatMap()**

Another option is use **flatMap** with a lambda expression that converts an empty Optional to an empty Stream instance, and non-empty Optional to a Stream instance containing only one element:

```
ArrayList<Test> testlist = valueList.stream()
  .flatMap(t -> t.isPresent() ? Stream.of(t.get()) : Stream.empty())
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can apply the same approach using method reference to converting an Optional to Stream:

```
ArrayList<Test> testlist = valueList.stream()
  .flatMap(t -> t.map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**3.Java 9's Optional::stream**

In Java 9, the stream() method has been added to the Optional class to improve its functionality.This is similar to the one showed in section 2, but this time we are using a predefined method for converting Optional instance into a Stream instance, If the Optional contains a value, then return a Stream containing the value. Otherwise, it returns an empty stream.

```
ArrayList<Test> testlist = valueList.stream()
  .flatMap(Optional::stream)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Java 8 Streams you can do it like this:

```java
    public static <T> List<T> unpackOptionals(List<Optional<T>> listOfOptionals) {
        return listOfOptionals.stream()
              .filter(Optional::isPresent)
              .map(Optional::get)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Using Java 9 or above, you can use the method `Optional.stream()` to do the job:

```java
    public static <T> List<T> unpackOptionals(List<Optional<T>> listOfOptionals) {
        return listOfOptionals.stream()
              .flatMap(Optional::stream)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

In Java 7 you shouldn't have any `Optional` (they were added in Java 8)