# How to convert an Optional<T> into a Stream<T>?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I want to prepend a stream with an Optional. Since `Stream.concat` can only concatinate Streams I have this question:

**How do I convert an Optional<T> into a Stream<T>?**

Example:

```
Optional<String> optional = Optional.of("Hello");
Stream<String> texts = optional.stream(); // not working
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725537/using-java-8s-optional-with-streamflatmap

Comment: That question indeed answers this one, but it presents a more complex example. I think this one is worth keeping for the simple case.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

In Java-9 the missing `stream()` method is added, so this code works:

```
Stream<String> texts = optional.stream();
```

See [JDK-8050820](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8050820). Download Java-9 [here](http://jdk.java.net/9/).

Answer (score 150):

If restricted with Java-8, you can do this:

```
Stream<String> texts = optional.map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty);
```

Comment: I upvoted this because Java 9 has some non-backward compatible changes for some projects in their current state. Some projects, such as [lombok](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/985), are part of core corporate artifacts that are slow to be changed.

Comment: If by any chance your optional happens to contain a `List<String>` instead of a single `String` object, you just need to replace `Stream::of` with `List::stream`. The same applies to any other type of collection. You can also just use `Collection::stream`. Else you will get a `Stream<List<String>>` which is probably _not_ what you wanted.

Comment: @walen the question is to convert an `Optional<T>` to `Stream<T>` if the T is `List<String>`, so be it. The answer stands correct still. What you might be looking for is flattening the collection. Aside, you are already on the wrong path if you have ended up using `Optional<Collection<T>>`.

Comment: @Naman No need to justify the answer — I didn't say it wasn't correct. I just gave a tip on how to apply this solution to an `Optional` containing a `List`, which is a scenario some people might encounter.

Answer (score 8):

You can do:

```
Stream<String> texts = optional.isPresent() ? Stream.of(optional.get()) : Stream.empty();
```

Comment: I'm not a big fan of `isPresent`, it feels like a legacy method to me and reminds me of the times before Java8. But thanks for providing an alternative solution.

Comment: Less fluent than the `map().orElseGet()` approach but probably slightly more efficient.

Answer (score 8):

I can recommend [Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#stream-java.util.Optional-)'s `Streams.stream(optional)` method if you are not on Java 9. A simple example:

```
Streams.stream(Optional.of("Hello"))
```

Also possible to static import `Streams.stream`, so you can just write

```
stream(Optional.of("Hello"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're on an older version of Java (lookin' at you, Android) and are using the [aNNiMON Lightweight Stream API](https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API), you can do something along the lines of the following:

```
    final List<String> flintstones = new ArrayList<String>(){{
        add("Fred");
        add("Wilma");
        add("Pebbles");
    }};

    final List<String> another = Optional.ofNullable(flintstones)
            .map(Stream::of)
            .orElseGet(Stream::empty)
            .toList();
```

This example just makes a copy of the list.

Answer (score 1):

It can depend of how you want to convert empty optional to stream element.
If you want to interpret it as "nothing" (or "no element"):

```
Stream<String> texts = optional.stream(); // since JDK 9
Stream<String> texts = optional.map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty); // JDK 8
```

But if you want to interpret it as null:

```
Stream<String> texts = Stream.of(optional.oreElse(null));
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice library from one of my ex collegues is Streamify. A lot of collectors, creating streams from practicly everything.

https://github.com/sourcy/streamify

Creating a stream form an optional in streamify:

```
Streamify.stream(optional)
```