# How to add two Optional<Long> in java

Tags: java, option-type

```
Optional<Long>totalLanding= ....(get it from somewhere);
Optional<Long>totalSharing = ...(get it from somewhere);
```

I want to do something like this not syntactically but logically

```
Optional<Long>total = totalLanding+totalSharing;
```

Such that if both are empty then total should be empty if one of them has the value then total should have that value is both of them have the value then they should get added and stored in total

Answer (score 9):

How about using `Stream`s?

```
Optional<Long> total = Stream.of(totalLanding,totalSharing)
                             .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                             .map(Optional::get)
                             .reduce(Long::sum);
```

BTW, I'd use `OptionalLong` instead of `Optional<Long>`.

The solution would be similar:

```
OptionalLong total = Stream.of(totalLanding,totalSharing)
                           .filter(OptionalLong::isPresent)
                           .mapToLong(OptionalLong::getAsLong)
                           .reduce(Long::sum);
```

Comment: You are forgetting that optional is a stream too. See my answer.

Comment: @kan You mean that `Optional` has a `stream()` method. `Optional` is not a `Stream`. And it's not that I forgot, I'm just less familiar with methods added after Java 8.

Comment: Agree, I meant logically it's a stream too, alas Java 8 lacks it. Seems Java 8 API authors forgot it then ;)

Answer (score 5):

Java 9 or newer:

```
Optional<Long>total = Stream.concat(
        totalLanding.stream(),
        totalSharing.stream())
    .reduce(Long::sum)
```

Java 8 compatible variant:

```
Optional<Long>total = Stream.concat(
        totalLanding.map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty),
        totalSharing.map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty))
    .reduce(Long::sum)
```

Or better to extract the `.map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty)` as a utility method and reuse. Or other variants here: [How to convert an Optional<T> into a Stream<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33942614/how-to-convert-an-optionalt-into-a-streamt)

Answer (score 0):

This should work with Java 8:

```
Optional<Long> total = totalLanding.map(x -> x + totalSharing.orElse(0L))
        .map(Optional::of)   // wrap it twice for the next line to find an Optional inside
        .orElse(totalSharing);
```

Comment: In Java 9 can be simplified to:
`first.map(x -> x + second.orElse(0L)).or(() -> second);`

Comment: @AlexanderTerekhov That's true, thanks. I should've stated that this is a bit more verbose just so it compiles with Java 8.

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
BigDecimal zero = BigDecimal.ZERO

Optional<Long> addition = Optional.of(totalLanding.orElse(zero).add(totalSharing.orElse(zero)));
```

Comment: Something like that was my idea too, but it wouldn't return an empty optional if neither was set.

Answer (score -2):

We can do like:

```
Optional<Long>result = Optional.of((totalLanding != null ? totalLanding.get() : 0L) + (totalSharing != null ? totalSharing.get() : 0L));
```

Comment: Have you actually tried that? This should lead to a NullPointerException if any of the Optionals is the result of `Optional.ofNullable(null)`.

Comment: Also does not work for requirement _if both are empty then total should be empty_