# java 8 alternative for nested for loops

Tags: java, arrays, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have the following snippet and I wonder if and how it is possible to replace it with Java-streams/Java 8 API

```
List<Borrower> borrowers = creditcomplex.getBorrowers();
for (Borrower borrower : borrowers) {
    List<Facility> facilities = borrower.getFaciliies();
    for (Facility facility : facilities) {
        List<RepaymentSchedule> repaymentScheduleList = facility.getrepaymentSchedule();
        if (repaymentScheduleList != null) {
            for (RepaymentSchedule repaymentschedule : repaymentScheduleList) {
                double[] repayment = 
                    amortizationService.calculateAmortizationSchedule(repaymentschedule);
                double[] drawdown = 
                    amortizationService.calculateRepaymentSchedule(repaymentschedule);
                double[] outstandingProfie = amortizationService
                        .calculateOutstandingSchedule(repaymentschedule);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd probably look to fold some of the above functionality into (say) the Borrower class, the Facility class etc. Then you can ask those classes and delegate, rather than pulling objects out of objects out of objects.... See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter for more on this.... You *may* need to pass the amortizationService around, note...

Answer (score 4):

You can use `flatMap`:

```
creditcomplex.getBorrowers().stream()
    .flatMap(b -> b.getFaciliies().stream())
    .flatMap(f -> Optional.ofNullable(f.getrepaymentSchedule()).stream())
    .forEach(repaymentschedule -> {
            double[] repayment = 
                amortizationService.calculateAmortizationSchedule(repaymentschedule);
            double[] drawdown = 
                amortizationService.calculateRepaymentSchedule(repaymentschedule);
            double[] outstandingProfie = amortizationService
                    .calculateOutstandingSchedule(repaymentschedule);
    });
```

P.S.1: Note that `Optional#stream` appeared in java 9, you might need to use:

```
optional.map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty)
```

It's taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33942615/7606764).

P.S.2: What you're doing in a `forEach` does not have any effect (you're declaring and initializing arrays inside, but you cannot use them outside of the loop. I left the code because it can be replaced with any computation on the nested elements.

P.S.3: Returning `null` instead of empty list is error prone and it's usually better to go with an empty list.

Comment: why use flatMap(f -> Optional.ofNullable(f.getrepaymentSchedule()).stream()) instead of juste : map(Facility::getrepaymentSchedule) ???

Comment: @ArnaultLePrévost-Corvellec because of the `null`-check. In the question it checks: `if (repaymentScheduleList != null)`, so I cannot simply write `f.getrepaymentSchedule().stream()` since that can result in NPE

Comment: @ArnaultLePrévost-Corvellec returning empty list instead of `null` is a better style, I have added it in P.S.3

Comment: nop you filter null object in next step of your stream ^^

Comment: perfectly aggre on list but stream can return null object filters method had been add in this purpose on J8 =)

Comment: @ArnaultLePrévost-Corvellec hah, you're right. I missed that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but it should roughly be

```
List<RepaymentSchedule> repaymentSchedules = creditcomplex.getBorrowers().stream()
    .flatMap(borrower -> borrower.getFacilities().stream())
    .map(facility -> facility.getrepaymentSchedule())
    .filter(repaymentScheduleList -> repaymentScheduleList != null)
    .flatMap(repaymentScheduleList -> repaymentScheduleList.stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

would be one thing, and from here youcan create the arrays.

Alternatively, you can omit the `.collect()` and instead do

```
.forEach(repaymentSchedule -> {
    double[] repayment = 
                amortizationService.calculateAmortizationSchedule(repaymentschedule);
    double[] drawdown = 
                amortizationService.calculateRepaymentSchedule(repaymentschedule);
    double[] outstandingProfie = amortizationService
                    .calculateOutstandingSchedule(repaymentschedule);
});
```