# Collect optional items

Tags: java, java-8, guava, collect

Given Guava Immutable table, i need to process all cell and and filter out some cells based on some mapper result which returns Java Optional,

```
  immutbleTable.cellSet()
            .parallelStream()
                .map(cell -> processAndGetOptionalResult(cell))
                .filter(cell -> cell.isPresent())
                .map(cell -> cell.get())
                .collect(Collector.of(
                        ImmutableTable.Builder::new,
                        ImmutableTable.Builder::put,
                        (l, r) -> l.putAll(r.build()),
                        ImmutableTable.Builder<String,String,String>::build)
            );
    }
```

Is there a better way to achieve this ? Is there a way that i can remove "map(cell -> cell.get())"  and collect cell.get() via accumulator itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can integrate the processing of the `Optional` into the `Collector`:

```
resultTable = immutableTable.cellSet().parallelStream()
    .map(cell -> processAndGetOptionalResult(cell))
    .collect(Collector.of(
            ImmutableTable.Builder::new,
            (b,o) -> o.ifPresent(b::put),
            (l, r) -> l.putAll(r.build()),
            ImmutableTable.Builder<String,String,String>::build)
    );
```

This works smoothly as the accumulator function represents an action and performing an action (if not empty) is one of the canonical use cases for an `Optional`, unlike the `isPresent`-`get` sequence.

Answer (score 3):

Besides using method references:

```
immutbleTable.cellSet()
        .parallelStream()
            .map(this::processAndGetOptionalResult)
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(Optional::get)
            .collect(Collector.of(
                    ImmutableTable.Builder::new,
                    ImmutableTable.Builder::put,
                    (l, r) -> l.putAll(r.build()),
                    ImmutableTable.Builder<String,String,String>::build)
        );
}
```

the answer is **no** - in current (JDK 8) API there is no better way to achieve that. In JDK 9 `Optional` will have `.stream()` method, which will allow using one operation - `flatMap`:

```
immutbleTable.cellSet()
        .parallelStream()
            .map(this::processAndGetOptionalResult)
            .flatMap(Optional::stream)
            .collect(Collector.of(
                    ImmutableTable.Builder::new,
                    ImmutableTable.Builder::put,
                    (l, r) -> l.putAll(r.build()),
                    ImmutableTable.Builder<String,String,String>::build)
        );
}
```

[For more details see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725537/using-java-8s-optional-with-streamflatmap).