# Java 8 collect() only isPresent() Optional values

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

Is there a more elegant way of practically achieving this in Java 8?

```
list.stream()
    .map(e -> myclass.returnsOptional(e))
    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
    .map(Optional::get)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I'm talking about `filter(Optional::isPresent)` followed by `map(Optional::get)`, I want to elegantly collect in a list only `Optional` results which have a value.

Comment: It looks fine to me. I'm not sure what you don't like about it.

Comment: If all your Optionals have a result this is not an Optional anymore... instead of returning an optional and checking if isPresent you can return nulls and filter, it'll be one step shorter. `list.stream().map(e -> myclass.returnsObjectOrNull(e)).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: .map(o -> o.map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty)) or see the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725537/using-java-8s-optional-with-streamflatmap

Comment: I do know in java9 that optional with have a stream, so rather than `filter` and `map`, you could do `flatMap(Optional::stream)` so if no one has an answer, keep it in mind for java9

Comment: @alfasin They don't all have a result

Comment: @Ash French That is exactly the kind of thing I was hoping for, it just felt like there would be a better way of doing it. Too bad it's only for Java 9 but will definitely keep in mind!

Comment: @khelwood Nothing in particular I don't like about it, it just felt there was a better built-in way, something along the lines of Ash's Java 9 example. Too bad it's not for Java 8

Comment: I understand that, what I'm saying is that instead of returning `Optional.empty()` from `myclass.returnsOptional` and then filter the empty results, you can simply return null and filter by `Objects::nonNull`

Comment: Can returnsOptional method be static?

Comment: Looks OK (and I have used this). Slight elegance improvement: `.map(myclass::returnsOptional)` instead of lambda

Answer (score 3):

In your case you can use one `flatMap` instead of combinations of `map` `filter` and again `map`. 
To Do that it's better to define a separate function for creating a Stream: `public private static Stream<Integer> createStream(String e)` to not have several lines of code in lambda expression.

Please see my full Demo example:

```
 public class Demo{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "Hi Stack!", "not", "5");
        List<Integer> newList = list.stream()
                .flatMap(Demo::createStream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(newList);
    }

    public static Stream<Integer> createStream(String e) {
        Optional<Integer> opt = MyClass.returnsOptional(e);
        return opt.isPresent() ? Stream.of(opt.get()) : Stream.empty();
    }
}


class MyClass {
    public static Optional<Integer> returnsOptional(String e) {
        try {
            return Optional.of(Integer.valueOf(e));
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
}
```

in case returnsOptional cannot be static you will need to use "arrow" expression instead of "method reference"

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if its so different but you could just filter based on your optional instead of getting the optional and filtering next. 
Something like this?

```
list.stream()
    .filter(e -> myclass.returnsOptional(e).isPresent())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Note**: This will only work if returnsOptional returns the same object type as your original list item types.

Comment: That's not going to produce the same list as the one the OP is producing.

Comment: hmm why wouldn't it?

Comment: Because `list` is of type say `Foo` and `myclass.returnsOptional(Foo)` returns `Optional<Bar>`. In the end I need `List<Bar>` and you are producing `List<Foo>`

Comment: I see. I didn't realize that your Optional returns a different type from your original question. Thanks for the explanation.