# How to obtain new list after groupby and sum over one attribute

Tags: java, group-by, aggregate, java-stream, collectors

I have a list of `Settlement` class which has the following attributes:

```
public class Settlement {
    private String contractNo;
    private String smartNo;
    private String dealTrackNo;
    private String buySellFlag;
    private String cashFlowType;
    private String location;
    private String leaseNo;
    private String leaseName;
    private double volume;
    private double price;
    private double settleAmount;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Now I would like to group the list of `Settlement` by `SmartNo` (String) and get the sum over `settleAmount` which becomes the new `settleAmount` for each `SmartNo`.

Since I am using Java 8, `stream` should be the way to go.

Groupby should be quite straight forward using the following code:

```
Map<String, List<Settlement>> map = list.stream()
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Settlement::getSmartNo));
System.out.println(map.getValues());
```

What if I want to get a new list after grouping by SmartNo and summing over settlementAmount? Most of the examples out there only shows how to print out the sums. What I am interested is how to get the aggregated list?

Comment: `stream` the entrySet and `map`, it to your result object, and `collect` it to a `List`.

Comment: @teppic Can you be more specific? I am quite new to Java 8. Not sure how to `map` it to my result object.

Comment: What type of object do you require in your result list? Is a simple tuple with your `SmartNo` and sum adequate?

Comment: @teppic these two and two others: volume and price

Comment: You want to sum volume, price, and settlementAmount for each smartNo?

Comment: @teppic, Actually volume is always same for `Settlement`s with same SmartNo, no need for price in new list. So `SmartNo`, `volume` and sum of `settleAmount` is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you need a [`toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) collector with custom merger like this:

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
       Settlement::getSmartNo,
       Function.identity(),
       (s1, s2) -> s1.addAmount(s2.getSettleAmount())));
```

With a helper method inside `Settlement` class:

```
Settlement addAmount(double addend) {
    this.settleAmount += addend;
    return this;
}
```

Comment: You really recommend a reduction function that modifies its argument?

Comment: @Holger, sure. Java is not Haskell. Sometimes it's good solution.

Comment: I thought, you know that this is *broken*. You are modifying arbitrary objects of the source list, without any control over which are modified and which not. I.e. with a parallel stream, different objects might get modified in each execution.

Comment: @Holger, please show me a counterexample when it could fail or show me a spec statement which states that my solution is *broken*.

Comment: You *know*, how the stream processing works, e.g. how the workload is split into chunks which are processing individually before the partial results are merged. In other words, that instead of `f.apply(f.apply(a, b), c)`, the implementation may call `f.apply(a, f.apply(b, c))`. Of course, the result in `a` will have the desired sum, but whether `b` will be modified, is unpredictable. Granted, the question doesn’t say anything about the desired behavior regarding modifications made to the source objects, but I’m a bit surprised that you are recommending such a solution without any note about it

Answer (score 2):

I think the not-too-complex way through is a new stream on each member of the `values()` of your map and then a `map()` and `reduce()`. I am mapping to a new class `AggregatedSettlement` with just the three fields `smartNo`, `volume` and `settleAmount` (the last will be the sum). And then reducing by summing the `settleAmount`s.

```
    List<AggregatedSettlement> aggregatedList = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Settlement::getSmartNo))
            .values()
            .stream()
            .map(innerList -> innerList.stream()
                    .map(settlm -> new AggregatedSettlement(settlm.getSmartNo(), 
                            settlm.getVolume(), settlm.getSettleAmount()))
                    .reduce((as1, as2) -> {
                        if (as1.getVolume() != as2.getVolume()) {
                            throw new IllegalStateException("Different volumes " + as1.getVolume() 
                                    + " and " + as2.getVolume() + " for smartNo " + as1.getSmartNo());
                        }
                        return new AggregatedSettlement(as1.getSmartNo(), as1.getVolume(), 
                                as1.getSettleAmount() + as2.getSettleAmount());
                    })
                    .get()
            )
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I am not too happy about the call to `get()` on the `Optional<AggregatedSettlement>` that I get from `reduce()`; usually you should avoid `get()`. In this case I know that the original grouping only produced lists of at least one element, so the the `reduce()` cannot give an empty optional, hence the call to `get()` will work. A possible refinement would be `orElseThrow()` and a more explanatory exception.

I am sure there’s room for optimization. I am really producing quite many more `AggregatedSettlement` objects than we need in the end. As always, don’t optimize until you know you need to.

Edit: If only for the exercise here’s the version that doesn’t construct superfluous `AggregatedSettlement` objects. Instead it creates *two* streams on each list from your map, and it’s 5 lines longer:

```
    List<AggregatedSettlement> aggregatedList = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Settlement::getSmartNo))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(entry -> {
                double volume = entry.getValue()
                        .stream()
                        .mapToDouble(Settlement::getVolume)
                        .reduce((vol1, vol2) -> {
                            if (vol1 != vol2) {
                                throw new IllegalStateException("Different volumes " + vol1 
                                        + " and " + vol2 + " for smartNo " + entry.getKey());
                            }
                            return vol1;
                        })
                        .getAsDouble();
                double settleAmountSum = entry.getValue()
                        .stream()
                        .mapToDouble(Settlement::getSettleAmount)
                        .sum();
                return new AggregatedSettlement(entry.getKey(), volume, settleAmountSum);
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Pick the one you find easier to read.

Edit 2: It seems from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22726869/5772882) that in Java 9 I will be able to avoid the call to `Optional.get()` if instead of `map()` I use `flatMap()` and instead of `get()` I use `stream()`. It will be 6 chars longer, I may still prefer it. I haven’t tried Java 9 yet, though (now I know what I’m going to do today :-) The advantage of `get()` is of course that it would catch a programming error where the inner list comes out empty.