# Remove empty Optionals from Stream using StreamEx

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, streamex

I'm searching for an elegant way to stream only non-empty `Optional` entries using the StreamEx library. Or the standard library, if it's possible.

Currently I'm using the following, rather verbose, approach:

```
List<Optional<String>> list = 
   Arrays.asList(Optional.of("A"), Optional.empty(), Optional.of("B"));

List<String> nonEmpty = 
   StreamEx.of(list).filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get).toList();
```

I'm essentially looking for something like StreamEx's [`nonNull`](https://static.javadoc.io/one.util/streamex/0.6.6/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#nonNull--) method, but for `Optional`.

Comment: Java 9: `List<String> nonEmpty =  list.stream().flatMap(Optional::stream).toList();`

Comment: you should add that as an answer actually, not a comment/edit. I would upvote... and SO encourages this also. good find!

Comment: I believe you have a wrong design, if you have that situation. You should not add elements which do not have their values. So I consider it as a wrong design, try to avoid using optional in that way.
Instead, give responsibility to your sources, where your data comes from, they should give you values, not empty placeholders.

Comment: @NikitaSalomatin I suppose, the list is just an example. The real life case might be more of `streamOfOrdinaryValues .map(functionThatReturnsOptional) /*the issue of the question*/ .toList();`…

Comment: @NikitaSalomatin: The example is condensed. You have a point, but I'd argue that the situation will often arise in real-world settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well this has been added, but only in java-9:

```
list.stream()
    .flatMap(Optional::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

There is a back-port from Stuart Marks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22726869)

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I'm on Java 8. Do have StreamEx available, though, and was hoping that it would have a shortcut similar to what you're showing.

Comment: @Henrik I'd just live with that, it's not that much of a big deal... until you upgrade to 9

Comment: But you can do shorter than Stuart Marks: `.flatMap(o -> o.map(Stream::of).orElse(null))`

Comment: @Holger beautiful! I could not understand it right away, but then *if a mapped Stream is null an empty stream is used, instead*

Answer (score 2):

A bit of research into the StreamEx issue backlog revealed [issue 49](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/issues/49), which provides a shorter approach and contains a discussion on the topic:

```
List<String> nonEmpty = StreamEx.of(list).flatMap(StreamEx::of).toList();
```

Shorter, although whether it's more readable is up for discussion.