# java lambda - how to traverse optional list/stream of optionals

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, option-type

Having an Optional List of Optional's like:

```
Optional<List<Optional<String>>> optionalList = Optional.of(
    Arrays.asList(
        Optional.empty(),
        Optional.of("ONE"),
        Optional.of("TWO")));
```

How to traverse `optionalList` to print out the string's `ONE` and `TWO` ?

What about having an Optional Stream of Optionals?

```
Optional<Stream<Optional<String>>> optionalStream = Optional.of(
    Stream.of(
        Optional.empty(),
        Optional.of("ONE"),
        Optional.of("TWO")));
```

Update: Thanks for answers, solution for optionalStream (non nested):

```
optionalStream
    .orElseGet(Stream::empty)
    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
    .map(Optional::get)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can also just map the `Optional` to a `Stream` instead of checking `isPresent` and getting the value yourself explicitly. Will be a bit more 'functional style'.

Comment: You should avoid storing `Optional` in collections, see [Uses for Optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454952/uses-for-optional) and [Is it Worth it to Use 'Optional' in Collections?](https://dzone.com/articles/is-it-worth-it-to-use-optional-in-collections)

Comment: @DidierL true, however this is still a valid exercise for the case of `Stream<Optional<T>>` which is much more common when the items in your collection are being mapped to an `Optional<T>` by some other function, so you end up with a `Stream<Optional<T>>`, which you then want to filter and convert to a `Stream<T>`.

Comment: Indeed, for me this was a valid case as well. Note that there is an [Optional.stream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#stream--) method introduced in Java 9 to avoid that (to combine with `flatMap()`). Finally, I would also avoid `Optional<List>` and `Optional<Stream>` as they are not very friendly to work with. Use empty lists/streams instead whenever possible as this makes far cleaner API's.

Comment: Yes true. (Refer to my answer about Java 9). Yes having an `Optional<List>` is not really considered good practice... ideally one returns an empty `List`, however I did encounter some cases where there was a difference between returning an empty list and not returning one at all. (Traditionally it would be returning a `null` instead of empty list.) Ideally one avoids this because it is confusing to the reader, but sometimes situations do arise which put you in a corner.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, check if the `Optional` is present. If yes, then stream the list and filter the non-empty ones and print each of them.

```
optionalList.ifPresent(list -> list.stream()
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(Optional::get)
            .forEach(System.out::println));
```

Almost similar for the stream case too

```
optionalStream.ifPresent(stream -> stream
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(Optional::get)
            .forEach(System.out::println));
```

Comment: adding a `.map(Optional::get)` will print the string

Answer (score 11):

You can indeed stream the `Option<String>` and filter only non empty values.

```
Optional<List<Optional<String>>> optionalList = Optional.of(Arrays.asList(Optional.empty(), Optional.of("ONE"), Optional.of("TWO")));

optionalList.orElseGet(ArrayList::new)
            .stream()
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(Optional::get)           
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

You can also use `Optional.ifPresent()` as suggested in another answers :

```
optionalList.ifPresent(l -> l.stream()
                             .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                             .map(Optional::get)                               
                             .forEach(System.out::println));
```

Personally I prefer the first way because it removes a nested level : I find it more pleasant to read.

Comment: The first way will create an empty `ArrayList` for nothing if the list does not exist.

Comment: It is right. But creating an empty `ArrayList` living in the scope of a stream execution costs also nothing.

Comment: I don't have an IDE handy, but wouldn't a `flatMap` squash the need for all of the `isPresent` checks?

Comment: @chrylis Yes. All these answers are so bloated, when all one needs to do is convert the `Optional` items in the list to a `Stream` and `flatMap` to it.

Answer (score 11):

If you can use Java 9, it can be done like this:

```
optionalList.ifPresent(list -> list.stream()
  .flatMap(Optional::stream)
  .forEach(System.out::println));
```

For a stream of optionals it would be the same, without the first `.stream()` call.

With Java 8 you don't have the `Optional::stream` method available so you can do it yourself:

```
optionalList.ifPresent(list -> list.stream()
  .flatMap(opt -> opt.map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty))
  .forEach(System.out::println));
```

And for a `Stream` of `Optional`s it would look like this:

```
optionalStream.ifPresent(stream -> stream
  .flatMap(opt -> opt.map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty))
  .forEach(System.out::println));
```

Comment: tried for a stream of optionals omitting first `.stream()` call - but not working (java 8)

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work? Just tried the Java 8 version, with the first line replaced to: `optionalStream.ifPresent(stream -> stream`  definitely works.

Answer (score 6):

```
optionalList.stream().flatMap(List::stream).filter(Objects::nonNull).forEach(...)
```

Comment: This version is nice because it avoids the creation of an empty list and skips right to the empty stream (but is only possible in Java 9+ when `Optional.stream` was introduced).

Answer (score 3):

As I see there are two ways, second one look a bit more pretty to me, take a look:

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Optional<String> element1 = Optional.of("test1");
        Optional<String> element2 = Optional.empty();
        Optional<String> element3 = Optional.of("test2");
        Optional<String> element4 = Optional.of("test3");
        List<Optional<String>> list = Arrays.asList(element1, element2, element3, element4);

        System.out.println(extractStrings1(list));
        System.out.println(extractStrings2(list));
    }

    private static List<String> extractStrings1(List<Optional<String>> list) {
        return list.stream()
                .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                .map(Optional::get)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static List<String> extractStrings2(List<Optional<String>> list) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        list.forEach(element -> element.ifPresent(result::add));
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well ...

1. Check whether the optional list is present.
2. Do a "for each" for all elements of the (now present) list.
3. In each step check whether the optional string is present.
4. If yes, print it.

A one-liner can do that:

```
optionalList.ifPresent(list -> list.forEach(s -> s.ifPresent(System.out::println)));
```