# Java's flatMap on list of list of optional integers

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I have the following bit of simplified code that fails to compile and I don't understand why:

```
List<Optional<Integer>> list =
    new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> flattened = 
  list
    .stream()
    .flatMap(i -> i)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The compiler tells me:

```
[ERROR] ... incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
[ERROR]     (argument mismatch; bad return type in lambda expression
[ERROR]       Optional<Integer> cannot be converted to Stream<? extends R>)
[ERROR]   where R,T are type-variables:
[ERROR]     R extends Object declared in method <R>flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Stream<? extends R>>)
[ERROR]     T extends Object declared in interface Stream
```

I admit I'm not used to Java but I have to for a project. I mocked this in Scala where `list.flatten` and the equivalent `list.flatMap(i => i)` work just as expected:

```
val list = List(Some(1), Some(2), None)
list.flatten // List(1, 2)
```

Is Java's `flatMap` different?

Comment: It depends on which version of java you are using, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725537/using-java-8s-optional-with-streamflatmap)

Comment: You cannot 'flatmap' single objects or a single collection. Flatmap combines streams into a single stream. Those streams, in turn, can come from collections using `.stream()` on each element like so: `.flatMap(i -> i.stream())`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It should be:

```
List<Integer> flattened = 
  list
    .stream()
    .filter (Optional::isPresent)
    .map(Optional::get)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Your `flatMap` expects a function that transforms a `Stream` element to a `Stream`. You should use `map` instead (to extract the value of the `Optional`). In addition, you need to filter out empty `Optional`s (unless you wish to transform them to `null`s).

Without the filtering:

```
List<Integer> flattened = 
  list
    .stream()
    .map(o -> o.orElse(null))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: "unless you wish to transform them to nulls" - calling `get()` on empty optional throws an exception.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlakJaros that's why I didn't call get on any empty Optional. I used orElse in the second solution

Comment: my point was that it sounds like you could skip the `filter` and just do `map(Optional::get)` and it will transform to null. You answer is good, I would just word it slightly different to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3):

> Is Java's flatMap different?

The `flatMap` method expects the function supplied to return a stream but `i -> i` doesn't provide that. In JDK8 you'll need to create a stream from the Optional then flatten:

```
 list.stream()
     .flatMap(i -> i.isPresent() ? Stream.of(i.get()) : Stream.empty())
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or in JDK9, in can be done as:

```
  list.stream()
      .flatMap(Optional::stream)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: But doesn't `stream()` make a stream out of the list?

Comment: @MaxPower the `stream` method for lists yes. the `stream` method on Optional's creates a stream of one element if the value is present else an empty stream.

Answer (score 3):

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) of `Stream.flatMap(Function<? extends T, ? extends Stream<? extends R>>)`:

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of replacing each element of this stream with the contents of a mapped stream produced by applying the provided mapping function to each element. Each mapped stream is closed after its contents have been placed into this stream. (If a mapped stream is `null` an empty stream is used, instead.)
>   This is an intermediate operation.
>
> **API Note:**
>
> The `flatMap()` operation has the effect of applying a one-to-many transformation to the elements of the stream, and then flattening the resulting elements into a new stream.

As you can see, the method is used to take each element, create a *stream* from them, then flatten each stream into a single stream (which is returned by the method). So doing:

```
List<Optional<Integer>> optionals = ...;
List<Integer> integers = optionals.stream()
        .flatMap(optional -> optional) // identity function
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Won't work as the function returns an `Optional` not a `Stream` of `Integer`s. To solve this you need to change the function to return a `Stream` of what the `Optional` contains. Depending on the version of Java you're using you can do:

Java 9+,

```
List<Optional<Integer>> optionals = ...;
List<Integer> integers = optionals.stream()
        .flatMap(Optional::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Java 8,

```
// There are different ways to convert an Optional into a Stream using
// flatMap, this is just one option. Holger shows other ways in the comments.
List<Optional<Integer>> optionals = ...;
List<Integer> integers = optionals.stream()
        .flatMap(optional -> optional.isPresent() ? Stream.of(optional.get()) : Stream.empty())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Other options include using `map` combined with `filter` or methods of `Optional`. See [Eran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53776520/6395627) for examples.

Comment: Or `.flatMap(optional -> optional.map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty))`. It would be even valid to use `.flatMap(optional -> optional.map(Stream::of).orElse(null))`