# Accumulate values and return result in Java stream

Tags: java, java-stream, java-11

I have a class with a collection of `Seed` elements. One of the method's return type of `Seed` is `Optional<Pair<Boolean, Boolean>>`.

I'm trying to loop over all `seeds`, keeping the return type (`Optional<Pair<Boolean, Boolean>>`), but I would like to be able to say if there was at least `true` value (in any of the `Pair`s) and override the result with it. Basically, if the collection is (skipping the `Optional` wrapper to make things simpler): [`Pair<false, false>`, `Pair<false, true>`, `Pair<false, false>`] I would like to return and `Optional` of `Pair<false, true>` because the second element had `true`. In the end, I'm interested if there was a `true` value and that's about it.

```java
  public Optional<Pair<Boolean, Boolean>> hadAnyExposure() {
    return seeds.stream()
        .map(Seed::hadExposure)
        ...
  }
```

I was playing with `reduce` but couldn't come up with anything useful.

> My question is related with Java streams directly. I can easily do this with a `for` loop, but I aimed initially for streams.

Comment: What is the type of `seeds`? also can you share what `Seed::hadExposure` do?

Comment: It's of type `Seed`, a custom type. But the important bit is that I'm working with a return type (inside that class) of `Optional<Pair<Boolean, Boolean>>`. I don't do anything with `seeds` except looping over them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725537/using-java-8s-optional-with-streamflatmap. I think this will help

Comment: what `Seed::hadExposure` return?

Comment: It returns `Optional<Pair<Boolean, Boolean>>`. I'm using `Pair` from `Apache Commons Lang3`, but in the end, it can be any tuple of two elements.

Comment: Not quite. I'm looking to return `Optional<Pair<Boolean, Boolean>>`, but first I do need to know if any of the `Pair` values had a `true` (`left` and/or `right`), and convert the return value accordingly. If the collection has 20 `Pair`s, and one of them is `true` on the `left`, and another one is `true` on the `right`, then the result is `Pair<true, true>`. Anything `true` on that side will turn the final value to `true` on the same side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thoughts on `reduce` look like the right way to go, using `||` to reduce both sides of each `Pair` together.  (Not exactly sure what your `Optional` semantics are, so going to filter out empty ones here and that might get what you want, but you may need to adjust):

```
Optional<Pair<Boolean, Boolean>> result = seeds.stream().map(Seed::hadExposure)
                .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                .map(Optional::get)
                .reduce((a, b) -> new Pair<>(a.first || b.first, a.second || b.second));
```

Comment: I was doing something like this based on @DHS comment: `seeds.stream().map(Seed::hadExposure).flatMap(Optional::stream).reduce((p, n) -> new ImmutablePair<>(n.getLeft() || p.getLeft(), n.getRight() || p.getRight()))`. I think your solution might work also. I'll test everything first.

Comment: Ok yeah, looks like that should be equivalent to what I have from what I can tell.

Answer (score 3):

## Straighforward

Since you're Java 11, you can use [`Optional::stream` (introduced in Java 9)](https://blog.codefx.org/java/java-9-optional/#stream) to get rid of the `Optional` wrapper. As a terminal operation, `reduce` is your friend:

```java
public Optional<Pair<Boolean, Boolean>> hadAnyExposure() {
    // wherever the seeds come from
    Stream<Optional<Pair<Boolean, Boolean>>> seeds = seeds();
    return seeds
        .flatMap(Optional::stream)
        .reduce((pair1, pair2) -> new Pair<>(
            pair1.left() || pair2.left(),
            pair1.right() || pair2.right())
    );
}
```

## Extended

If you want to go a step further and give your `Pair` a general way to be folded with another `Pair` into a new instance, you can make the code a bit more expressive:

```java
public class Pair<LEFT, RIGHT> {

    private final LEFT left;
    private final RIGHT right;

    // constructor, equals, hashCode, toString, ...

    public Pair<LEFT, RIGHT> fold(
            Pair<LEFT, RIGHT> other,
            BinaryOperator<LEFT> combineLeft,
            BinaryOperator<RIGHT> combineRight) {
        return new Pair<>(
            combineLeft.apply(left, other.left),
            combineRight.apply(right, other.right));
    }

}

// now you can use fold and Boolean::logicalOr
// https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Boolean.html#logicalOr(boolean,boolean)

public Optional<Pair<Boolean, Boolean>> hadAnyExposure() {
    Stream<Optional<Pair<Boolean, Boolean>>> seeds = seeds();
    return seeds
        .flatMap(Optional::stream)
        .reduce((pair1, pair2) -> pair1
            .fold(pair2, Boolean::logicalOr, Boolean::logicalOr))
    );
}
```

I probably wouldn't create `Pair::fold` just for this use case, but I would be tempted. ;)

Answer (score 1):

As you've tagged this question with `java-11`, you can make use of the [`Optional.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#stream()) method:

```
public Optional<Pair<Boolean, Boolean>> hadAnyExposure() {
    return Optional.of(
        seeds.stream()
             .flatMap(seed -> seed.hadExposure().stream())
             .collect(
                 () -> new Pair<Boolean, Boolean>(false, false),
                 (p, seed) -> { 
                     p.setLeft(p.getLeft() || seed.getLeft());
                     p.setRight(p.getRight() || seed.getRight()); 
                 },
                 (p1, p2) -> {
                     p1.setLeft(p1.getLeft() || p2.getLeft());
                     p1.setRight(p1.getRight() || p2.getRight());
                 }));
}
```

This first gets rid of the `Optional` by means of the `Optional.stream` method (keeping just the pairs) and then uses [`Stream.collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer)) to *mutably* reduce the pairs by means of the OR *associative* operation.

Note: using `Stream.reduce` would also work, but it would create a lot of unnecessary intermediate pairs. That's why I've used `Stream.collect` instead.

Comment: Probably I didn't make myself clear, but I need to know, from all the `Pair`s, if there are `true` values in both sides (`left` and `right`) and account for those in the final result.

Comment: @x80486 Now I understood what you were after. Please check if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

using `Collectors.partitioningBy` you can get a Map with boolean keys after that you can easily retrieve values indexed with the key true

```
Optional<Pair<Boolean, Boolean>> collect = Arrays.asList(pair1, pair2, par3).stream()
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(Optional::get)
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.partitioningBy(p -> p.getFirst() == true || p.getSecond() == true),
                    m -> m.get(true).stream().findAny()));
```